# JW player assign file through variable

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

```
playlist: [{

        "sources": [{"type": "video/mp4", "label": "SD", "file": "src.mp4"}] 
}],
```

how can use js variable to assign video file src like

```
playlist: [{
"sources": [{"type": "video/mp4", "label": "SD", "file": myvariable    }] 
}],
```

Comment: your variable must be an url or a blob file converted on a url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `file` is a string representing the location of the file. It's usually an absolute url. The demo doesn't function on SO for some reason✎, but it functions as a [**PLUNKER**](http://embed.plnkr.co/IJ4RGq3tWxiiBnJXjcQF/)

**Note:** I used ES6 [Template Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead of the usual [String Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String). If you intend to cater to IE users, you'll have to use [String Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

### Demo [PLUNKER](http://embed.plnkr.co/IJ4RGq3tWxiiBnJXjcQF/)

### Demo STACK (Does not function✎, review [PLUNKER](http://embed.plnkr.co/IJ4RGq3tWxiiBnJXjcQF/) instead)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/12/jwplayer.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="x">...</div>
  <script>
    var file = '023642.mp4';

    var jwp = jwplayer('x');
    jwp.setup({
      playlist: [{
        file: `http://media6000.dropshots.com/photos/1381926/20170326/${file}`
      }],
      width: 320,
      height: 180
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

✎ Unrelated to OP, but in regards to this Stack's functionality, see [@TinyGiant detailed answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355601/2813224)